# first cell in tableview array index out of range error

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview in which the first cell is different from all the others (I have two custom cells in the table dequeued With different Identifiers). The codes are as below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("profileCell") as! SbProfileViewCell

        //cell.textArea.text = bio[indexPath.row]

        //pictureFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (fileData, error) -> Void in

            if let pic = UIImage(data: fileData!) {

                cell.imageView.image = pic
            }
        }

        return cell

    } else {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell") as! SbPostsTableViewCell

        cell.date.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dates[indexPath.row - 1])

        pictureFileOne[indexPath.row - 1].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (fileOneData, error) -> Void in

            if let downloadedImageOne = UIImage(data: fileOneData!) {

                cell.imageArea.image = downloadedImageOne
            }
        }

        cell.textArea.text = text[indexPath.row - 1]

        return cell
    }
}
```

i'm getting the array out of index error for the commented lines and i'm also uncertain about whether using [indexPath.row - 1] would yield the effect I want (I want the second cell of the tableview to display the first object in the array), hope i explained everything ok, please help! thanks

**EDIT**

```
    var dates = [NSDate]()
    var autoBio = [String]()

    func getPosts() {

    let getPostsQuery = PFQuery(className: "allPosts")

    getPostsQuery.whereKey("userId", equalTo: userNumber)

    getPostsQuery.limit = 15
    getPostsQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    getPostsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts, error) -> Void in

        if let posts = posts {

            self.dates.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for post in posts {

                self.dates.append(post.createdAt as NSDate!)
            }
        }
        print(self.dates.count)
    }
}

    func getBio() {

    let bioQuery = PFQuery(className: "bios")

    bioQuery.whereKey("userId", equalTo: userNumber)
    bioQuery.limit = 1

    bioQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (bios, error) -> Void in

        if let bios = bios {

            self.bio.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            for bio in bios {

                self.bio.append(bio["about"] as! String)
            }
        }
    }

    print(self.bio.count)
}
```

i put getPosts() and getBio() in viewDidLoad. And I tried printing the bio and dates count as the end of these func and they do return a number > 0 so the arrays should be filled. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Answer would depend on how bio & pictureFile got filled (if they did at all), no?

Comment: can you share your array code?
and you must use [indexPath.row-1]  as you want to show second cell having details of first element of the array.

Comment: @ScottHunter  I've updated my question with my array codes, please see if there's anything wrong, thanks!

Comment: In the functions you use `self.bio`, but in the problematic code you use `bio`; why?  And did you verify that `bio` isn't empty at the point where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using the first cell as Section Header cell...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("profileCell") as! SbPostsTableViewCell

    return cell

}
```

Comment: this a good idea! i tried putting it in and changing the [indexPath.row - 1] back to [indexPath.row] but I'm still getting the error as stated in my title, any idea why?

Comment: How are you setting up your numberOfRowsInSection ?? It should look something like this:
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return yourArray.count
    }

Comment: it seems to be working now except the header does not scroll with the tableview? is there any way to fix it? thanks

Comment: You're probably using Plain Table View: "A plain table view can have one or more sections, sections can have one or more rows, and each section can have its own header or footer title. When the user scrolls through a section with many rows, the header of the section floats to the top of the table view and the footer of the section floats to the bottom."
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html
Try changing to Grouped Table View